# Javascript how to put a checkmark for the list item that was picked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html code. There is two buttons each of the buttons have list item under them. Here is the html code:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="dropdown pull-left">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        View
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li role="presentation">
          <a data-bind="click: function() { format('sgml_as_html') }">
            Show Tags
          </a>
        </li>

        <li role="presentation">
          <a data-bind="click: function() { format('html') };">
           Quick View
          </a>
        </li>

        <li role="presentation">
          <a data-bind="click: function() { format('show_link_targets') };">
            Show Link Targets
          </a>
        </li>

        <li role="presentation">
          <a data-bind="click: function() { format('show_all_link_targets') };">
            Show All Link Targets
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown pull-left" style="margin-left: 10px;">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown_menu_preview" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Preview
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_menu_preview">
        <li>
          <a data-bind="click: function() { format('bwd_preview') };">
            BWD Preview
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a data-bind="click: function() { format('blaw_preview') };">
            BLAW Preview (Coming Soon)
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>

          <a data-bind="click: function() { format('print_preview') };">
            Print Preview (default Notif Format)
          </a>
        </li>


      </ul>
    </div>



    </div>
```

I would like to see how in java script i can add a check mark for the list item thats picked. Here is the html Unicode character i would like to use the check mark listed in the link: http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp

Comment: Can you put together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com)?

Comment: Looks like you're using KnockoutJS... have you checked there docs?

Comment: @AdamJeffers I checked there cite couldn't find anything. I am really beginner with the knockout stuff. Unless you can point me to right documentation to follow to get this done.

Comment: @MarkC. It's going to hard to put a jsfiddle together with the knockout stuff.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. You have to do something like this.

```
<span data-bind="visible: format() == 'show_link_targets'"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
```